# Is write to Firestore subcollection counted as a write to parent collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to estimate the rate of write operations to collections and subcollections in my application. Let's say there is a collection of documents called `parents`. Each document in `parents` has a subcollection called `childs`.

How write rate limit is calculated for `childs` subcollection writes? As a separate value (like for a separate collection), or it's added to a write rate value of `parents` collection?

I presume that the write rate limit should be calculated separately for each subcollection and parent collection, but I haven't found this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How write rate limit is calculated for childs subcollection writes? As a separate value (like for a separate collection), or it's added to a write rate value of parents collection?

It's counted as a separate read. The `parents` and `childs` collections are not related in terms of pricing.

> I presume that write rate limit should be calculated separately for each subcollection and parent collection, but I haven't found this in the documentation.

You are guessing right.

Comment: What about for subcollection group queries? Does the 500 writes/sec limit on a collection with sequentially-valued indexed fields apply to each subcollection in the group or in the aggregate?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, it does.